# Achar path de um file apenas dado o nome

Tags: c, path

Tou a tentar achar o path de um file apenas sabendo o seu nome. Ja tentei de várias formas incluindo `pwd` mas nao me serve de nada. **Existirá alguma maneira de o fazer ?** (Tenho garantia que esse é o unico ficheiro com esse nome , para nao haver paths diferentes)

Comment: de que arquivo você pretende pegar o endereço? tem algum código começado?

Comment: Podes usar as funcionalidades do teu Sistema Operativo. Por exemplo, para encontrar um ficheiro com o nome "FOO.BAR" em Windows (pesquisa dentro da directoria corrente): `dir /s /a /b foo.bar`; em Un\*x (pesquisa a partir da *root*): `find / -iname foo.bar`.

Comment: Você precisa ser mais específico com a sua pergunta: 1) você deseja encontrar um arquivo em uma árvore de diretórios? - 2) você deseja saber o path completo de um determinado arquivo ? - 3) você deseja saber o diretório base de um determinado arquivo?

Answer (score 0):

Se estiveres num sistema POSIX podes usar a [função ntfw()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html).

Ou então escreves uma função recursiva que examina uma directoria à procura do ficheiro.